# Stored Procedure SELECT UPDATE Incorrect Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure, which I intend on running via a job every 24 hours. I am able to successfully run the procedure query but for some reason the values dont seem to make sense. See below.

This is my table and what it looks like prior to the running of the procedure, using the following statement:

```
SELECT HardwareAssetDailyAccumulatedDepreciationValue,
HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue FROM HardwareAsset
```

[image]

I then run the following procedure (with the intention of basically copying the value in DailyDepreciationValue to DepreciationValue):

```
BEGIN

SELECT HardwareAssetID, HardwareAssetDailyAccumulatedDepreciationValue,
HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue FROM HardwareAsset
WHERE HardwareAssetDailyAccumulatedDepreciationValue IS NOT NULL

UPDATE HardwareAsset SET HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue = CASE WHEN
(HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue IS NULL) THEN
CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),HardwareAssetDailyAccumulatedDepreciationValue) ELSE
CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),(HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue + HardwareAssetDailyAccumulatedDepreciationValue))
END

END
```

But when i re-run the select statement the results are as follows:

[image]

It really doesnt make any sense to me at all any ideas?

Comment: `SET AccTotal = ISNULL(AccTotal, 0) + AccDaily`

Comment: @Malk, I gave it a go, same results.

Comment: What are the datatypes on the columns?

Comment: Can you provide table structure and sample data?

Comment: @Malk, the data types are both DECIMAL(7,2), the Daily column is a computed column, I think I have worked out why the second two change, its because of the computed column select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to replicate. We need more detail on the table structure and data. This is what I used to attempt to replicate. Feel free to modify as needed:

```
create table #t (
      AccD1 decimal(7,2)
    , AccD2 decimal(7,2)
    , AccDaily as AccD1 + AccD2
    , AccTotal decimal(7,2)
)

insert #t values 
      (100, 7.87,  null)
    , (300, 36.99, null)
    , (400, 49.32, null)
    , (100, 50.00, 100)

select * from #t

update #t set 
      AccTotal = isnull(AccTotal, 0) + AccDaily
    , AccD1 = 0
    , AccD2 = 0

select * from #t

drop table #t
```

Comment: the problem is. that the computed column uses the static column in its calculation. I know that sounds incredibly bad programming, but it makes sense when determining the calculation. I think the issue I am having is, that during the update, I am selecting the computed column which changes the values. I think I need to declare a temp value, store daily in there. Then update the static column with the temp value.

Comment: Right on. That should get you going. Good luck!